# Error while running python ginplut command

Tags: python, matplotlib, interactive, ginput

I'm trying to read (x, y) values from a series of plots with `ginput`; however, when running the code I get the following error and everything freezes!!

```
QTimer::singleShot: Timers cannot have negative timeouts
```

How can I solve this issue?

```
# EXAMPLE code:
for loop in range(10):
    x = np.linspace(1,10)
    y = np.sin(loop*x)
    plt.plot(x, y)
    points = plt.ginput(-1, -1)
    print(points)
    plt.show()
```